# Input validation with directives

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I'm currently working on a server using GraphQL and I'm stuck on implementing input validation with directives. What I'm trying to do is to add directives to input types which allow me to verify the input given before passing it to the actual data fetcher.
schema:

```
directive @email on INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION
type Mutation {
   getAccounts(filter: InutAccount): [Account] 
}
input InputAccount{
   email: String @email
}
```

I've done the wiring and schema building part, the mutation works, but I'm having problems with implementing the schema which allows me to validate an email (ex: email has to contain "@gmail.com").

Answer (score 1):

Input validation through directives do not work out of the box. I suggest two way of solving this.

**Without external library - The resolver is in charge of the validation**

This is the most basic solution. Your data fetcher (resolver), must return a DataFetcherResult, that may contain one or more GraphQLError. In the data fetcher, you can implement your validation, populate the DataFetcherResult GraphQLError and if no error is found perform your mutation.

This can be improved by mapping your GraphQL input object with a POJO, as graphl-java-tools would do, and use javax annotations and validators to validate your input before processing it.

**With GraphQL-Java Extended Validation Library -** https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-validation

This library does what you want and provides you some basic directives and associated constraints. Be aware the library is pretty new (there are a couple of bugs regarded nested inputs validation).